# Why does $\dfrac{8}{\frac{8\sqrt{145}}{145}} = \sqrt{145}$?

Tags: fractions, radicals

I can't seem to work out why this is true: $$\frac{8}{\dfrac{8\sqrt{145}}{145}} = \sqrt{145}$$

Could someone break it down for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \ \dfrac{8}{8 x}\, =\, \dfrac{1}x\,\ $ so $\,\ x = \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}n\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{1}x\, = \, \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\, =\, \dfrac{\sqrt{n}^2}{\sqrt{n}}\, =\, \sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{8}{\frac{8\sqrt{145}}{145}}&=\frac{8}{\frac{8}{\sqrt{145}}} & \text{because }\frac{\sqrt{145}}{145}=\frac 1{\sqrt{145}} \\
&=8\cdot\frac{\sqrt{145}}8 & \text{take reciprocal} \\
&=\sqrt{145} & \text{the $8$'s cancel}
\end{align}

Comment: Why does $\frac{\sqrt{145}}{145} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{145}}$?

Comment: @user11406 $\displaystyle{\frac{\sqrt{145}}{145} = \frac{\sqrt{145}}{\sqrt{145}\sqrt{145}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{145}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$8\left(\dfrac{145}{8\sqrt{145}}\right)=\dfrac{145}{\sqrt{145}}=\dfrac{145\sqrt{145}}{145}=\sqrt{145}$

Comment: This is complicated than it needs to be.  One can write $\dfrac{145}{\sqrt{145}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{145}\sqrt{145}}{\sqrt{145}}$ and then cancel.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{8}{\frac{8\sqrt{145}}{145}}$ = $8\cdot \frac{145}{8\sqrt{145}}$.

Here, the $8$s cancel. So,

$\frac{145}{\sqrt{145}} = 145^1\cdot 145^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 145^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{145}$.

Comment: You have a typo in your penultimate expression ;)